# How to disable adb port forwarding?

Tags: android, adb

How do I disable a port forwarding rule in adb that was previously enabled with

```
    adb forward tcp:1234 tcp:1234
```

Is there any other way than killing and restarting the adb server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Setting Up Redirection through ADB
>
> The Android Debug Bridge (ADB) tool provides port forwarding, an alternate way for you to set up network redirection. For more information, see Forwarding Ports in the ADB documentation.
>
> You can also remove a redirection by killing the ADB server.

However you can use network redirection provided by emulator console, which provide ways of removing. To access type:

> telnet localhost emulator_port

usually first emulator runs on port 5554.

use command "rdir" to add, del or list network redirections.

See documentation in [Using Network Redirection](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#redirection).

Good luck.

**EDIT:**

To stop forwarding use

`adb forward --remove tcp:<port>`, or `adb forward --remove-all`.

This was added to adb in December 2012 ([see patch here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/46371/)). The SDK update released for Android 4.3 (API 18) was the first to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adb forward --remove tcp:8080, or adb forward --remove-all.

This was added to adb in December 2012

Comment: The SDK update released for Android 4.3 (API 18) was the first to support it. You can [see the patch here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/46371/)

Comment: This also applies to `adb reverse --remove-all`